# What would happen if I set up a host named 'com' on a local network?

Tags: networking, dns, domain-name

According to [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fully_qualified_domain_name), fully qualified host names end with a trailing period. Jonathan de Boyne-Pollard writes in [No, that dot in the domain name of the URL is *not* a mistake](http://homepage.ntlworld.com/jonathan.deboynepollard/FGA/web-fully-qualified-domain-name.html) (emphasis mine):

> > I omitted the trailing dot in the domain name in the http://example.com./ URL because it was a typographical error.
>
> No, it wasn't. It was there for a reason. It made the domain name a fully qualified one, **and thus unambiguous and not prone to search path spoofing.**

I can use relative host names to refer to hosts within the same domain. What would happen if I set up a host named `com` on a local network? `google.com.` should still refer to Google as it's clearly fully qualified, but what about `google.com`? *Shouldn't* it refer to the machine in my local network? *Would* it? Why (not)? What network setup or services influence the behavior?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The behaviour of a local name that conflicts with a top-level domain is not well defined and may vary from one stub resolver to another. Therefore, the most useful answer to your question is: don't do it; if you do, you're asking for surprises.

The most likely defacto behaviour you're likely to encounter is glibc's behaviour as documented in the [resolv.conf manpage](http://linux.die.net/man/5/resolv.conf). Assuming a search list is configured with your local domain appearing in it (briefly, either `domain` or `search` appears in `/etc/resolv.conf` and contain your local domain), your local host **com.yourdomain.example.com.** will take priority over the top-level domain **com.** when you query for **com**. Yet even so, it's a bad idea to rely on that, because in case the local search list is misconfigured, you will get the top-level domain **com.** instead of an error, which can lead to a possible information leak (especially if **com.** had resource records other than SOA and NS, which it doesn't, but still, don't take chances).